# Different number of samples for different functions

Tags: gnuplot

```
plot x+3 , x**2+5*x+12
```

Is it possible to set `x+3` to have only 2 samples and `x**2+5*x+12` to have say 1000 samples in the same plot?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, but not out-of-the-box.

The first variant uses a temporary file to save one function with a low sampling rate and plotting it later together with the high-resolution function:

```
set samples 2
set table 'tmp.dat'
plot x+3
unset table
set samples 1000
plot 'tmp.dat' w lp t 'x+3', x**2 + 5*x + 12
```

This has the advantage, that you can use any sampling rates for both functions.

For you special case of `2` samples for one function, it can be done without an external file, but it involves quite some tricking:

```
set xrange [-10:10]
s = 1000
set samples s
f1(x) = x + 3

set style func linespoints
set style data linespoints
plot '+' using (x0 = (($0 == 0 || $0 == (s-1) )? $1 : x0), \
                ($0 < (s-2) ? 1/0 : x0)):(f1(x0)) t 'x+3',\
     x**2 + 5*x + 12
```

What I did here is:

1. Use the special filename `+` to generate a set of coordinates in the current `xrange`. This must be set, no autoscaling is possible.
2. Skipping all points but the first and the last by giving them the value `1/0` doesn't work, because the two remaining points aren't connected.
3. So I store the first `x`-value (when `$0`, or `column(0)` equals `0`) and use it when I encountered the second last points. For the last points, the usual values are used.

That works for your special case of `2` samples.

You must keep in mind, that the first function is treated as data, so you must use both `set style data` and `set style func` (just to show it).

The result with 4.6.4 is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if different *samplings* (as opposed to different ranges) are possible with gnuplot 5.x. If I missed that please let me know.

Here is a suggestion to have two different samplings in the same plot command without temporary files (or datablocks from gnuplot 5.0 on).
A requirement is a known xrange, i.e. it will work with autoscale only if you plot and replot the graph to automatically get `xmin` and `xmax`. For the second function you could also use `'+' u 1:(f2($1)) w lp`.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=4.4.0, March 2010)

```
### different samplings in one plot command
reset

set xrange[xmin=-10:xmax=10]

f1(x) = x+3
f2(x) = x**2 + 5*x + 12

s1  = 3                       # sampling 1
s2  = 101                     # sampling 2
set samples (s1>s2?s1:s2)     # the higher value
dx1 = real(xmax-xmin)/(s1-1)  # determine dx1 for f1

plot '+' u (x0=xmin+$0*dx1):(f1(x0)) every ::0::s1-1 w lp pt 7 ti sprintf("%d samples",s1), \
     f2(x) w lp pt 7 ti sprintf("%d samples",s2)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]