# Evaluating a computationally intensive function in gnuplot with smaller step-size

Tags: linux, matlab, plot, gnuplot, wolfram-mathematica

I have a couple of fairly large functions, which are sums of many individual gaussian functions with different prefactors and widths. My gnuplot code looks like this:

```
set terminal wxt size 350,262 enhanced font 'Verdana,10' persist
set border linewidth 1.5
set style line 1 linecolor rgb '#0060ad' linetype 1 linewidth 4
set style line 2 linecolor rgb '#660000' linetype 1 linewidth 4 
set style line 3 linecolor rgb '#00CC00' linetype 1 linewidth 4
set yrange [0:1]
set xrange[3:6]
f(x)=((0.0793*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4347)**2))+0.0800*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4315)**2))+0.0793*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4398)**2))+0.0749*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4251)**2))+0.0797*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4371)**2))+0.0764*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4295)**2))+0.0786*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4368)**2))+0.0795*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4375)**2))+0.0790*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4272)**2))+0.0795*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4414)**2))+0.0790*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4482)**2))+0.0747*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4446)**2))+0.0786*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4585)**2))+0.0798*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4283)**2))+0.0768*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4028)**2))+0.0788*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4343)**2))+0.0738*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3740)**2))+0.0797*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4342)**2))+0.0805*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4228)**2))+0.0771*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4009)**2))+0.0812*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4079)**2))+0.0808*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4323)**2))+0.0789*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4418)**2))+0.0758*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4069)**2))+0.0709*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3964)**2))+0.0769*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4018)**2))+0.0774*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4507)**2))+0.0714*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3642)**2))+0.0764*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4080)**2))+0.0783*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4222)**2))+0.0797*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4319)**2))+0.0762*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4001)**2))+0.0811*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4171)**2))+0.0801*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4216)**2))+0.0754*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4188)**2))+0.0747*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3767)**2))+0.0789*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4452)**2))+0.0797*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4040)**2))+0.0795*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4421)**2))+0.0796*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3906)**2))+0.0797*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4459)**2))+0.0793*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4214)**2))+0.0810*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4142)**2))+0.0783*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4076)**2))+0.0757*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4690)**2))+0.0776*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4357)**2))+0.0716*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3675)**2))+0.0807*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3827)**2))+0.0801*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4332)**2))+0.0760*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4393)**2))+0.0749*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3724)**2))+0.0787*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4301)**2))+0.0799*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4089)**2))+0.0787*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3916)**2))+0.0753*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4476)**2))+0.0754*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3777)**2))+0.0766*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4703)**2))+0.0786*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4208)**2))+0.0718*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4007)**2))+0.0767*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4319)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9155)**2))+0.0005*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9031)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9037)**2))+0.0008*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8955)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9111)**2))+0.0004*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8962)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9093)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9075)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9022)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9229)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9113)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8910)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9112)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8976)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9019)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8954)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8875)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9028)**2))+0.0006*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8976)**2))+0.0019*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8904)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9004)**2))+0.0003*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9130)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8906)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8870)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8985)**2))+0.0003*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8955)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8941)**2))+0.0004*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8826)**2))+0.0010*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8964)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8996)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8934)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9026)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8916)**2))+0.0007*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9097)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8979)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8959)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8975)**2))+0.0003*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8903)**2))+0.0003*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9197)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8941)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9022)**2))+0.0006*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9088)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9018)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8844)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9059)**2))+0.0009*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9202)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8732)**2))+0.0010*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9074)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9055)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9088)**2))+0.0008*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8901)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9154)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8891)**2))+0.0005*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9097)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9153)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9100)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9048)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8982)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8932)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9046)**2))+2.7670*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.7032)**2))+2.9711*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.7033)**2))+2.9772*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6772)**2))+2.0550*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6533)**2))+2.9235*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6911)**2))+2.5655*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6638)**2))+2.5437*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6866)**2))+3.0695*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6982)**2))+2.8722*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6635)**2))+2.7148*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.7035)**2))+3.0630*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6869)**2))+2.3065*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6599)**2))+0.9671*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6695)**2))+3.0357*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6881)**2))+2.1522*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6797)**2))+3.0028*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6803)**2))+1.6119*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6650)**2))+3.0935*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6915)**2))+2.9358*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6770)**2))+2.3817*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6633)**2))+2.9768*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6827)**2))+3.0612*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.7063)**2))+3.0828*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6756)**2))+2.1927*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6610)**2))+1.3756*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6947)**2))+2.0348*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6810)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6284)**2))+1.3065*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6527)**2))+2.7386*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6360)**2))+2.7516*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6692)**2))+3.0844*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6761)**2))+1.9341*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6949)**2))+3.0940*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6885)**2))+3.0564*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6738)**2))+2.0429*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6726)**2))+1.8376*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6773)**2))+3.0759*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6800)**2))+2.5849*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6705)**2))+2.8534*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6993)**2))+2.7325*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6754)**2))+3.0306*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6906)**2))+2.3818*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6904)**2))+3.0848*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6909)**2))+2.5889*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6768)**2))+2.6985*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6831)**2))+2.4830*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6844)**2))+1.6134*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6569)**2))+2.8258*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6784)**2))+3.0231*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6789)**2))+2.3088*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6877)**2))+1.8982*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6719)**2))+2.4061*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6982)**2))+0.0539*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.5631)**2))+2.2844*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6801)**2))+2.2014*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.7060)**2))+1.4783*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6764)**2))+2.7217*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6619)**2))+2.6972*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6604)**2))+1.4024*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6591)**2))+2.0910*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6874)**2)))/60)
g(x)=((0.0738*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3801)**2))+0.0794*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4161)**2))+0.0791*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4211)**2))+0.0651*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3033)**2))+0.0789*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4308)**2))+0.0792*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4280)**2))+0.0793*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4299)**2))+0.0806*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4163)**2))+0.0754*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3969)**2))+0.0632*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3034)**2))+0.0806*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3993)**2))+0.0769*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3983)**2))+0.0765*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4285)**2))+0.0788*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4216)**2))+0.0708*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3663)**2))+0.0798*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4032)**2))+0.0799*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4373)**2))+0.0773*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4429)**2))+0.0661*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3156)**2))+0.0765*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4017)**2))+0.0770*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4295)**2))+0.0741*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4371)**2))+0.0804*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3891)**2))+0.0802*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4372)**2))+0.0780*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4040)**2))+0.0805*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4242)**2))+0.0739*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3819)**2))+0.0793*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4202)**2))+0.0773*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4335)**2))+0.0802*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4349)**2))+0.0809*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4285)**2))+0.0795*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4246)**2))+0.0782*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4389)**2))+0.0763*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4120)**2))+0.0792*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4344)**2))+0.0760*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4073)**2))+0.0803*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4349)**2))+0.0777*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4692)**2))+0.0794*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4351)**2))+0.0739*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3731)**2))+0.0789*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4349)**2))+0.0794*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4424)**2))+0.0763*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4220)**2))+0.0787*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3948)**2))+0.0794*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4222)**2))+0.0685*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3289)**2))+0.0678*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3206)**2))+0.0791*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4374)**2))+0.0791*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4269)**2))+0.0816*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4066)**2))+0.0649*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.2722)**2))+0.0749*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3994)**2))+0.0731*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3780)**2))+0.0787*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4422)**2))+0.0794*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4252)**2))+0.0756*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4151)**2))+0.0801*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4390)**2))+0.0800*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4392)**2))+0.0798*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4369)**2))+0.0787*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4304)**2))+0.0810*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4151)**2))+0.0731*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3687)**2))+0.0787*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4244)**2))+0.0810*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4019)**2))+0.0726*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3758)**2))+0.0791*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4271)**2))+0.0790*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4275)**2))+0.0812*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4212)**2))+0.0794*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4242)**2))+0.0758*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3431)**2))+0.0774*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3918)**2))+0.0805*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4335)**2))+0.0686*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3211)**2))+0.0804*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4130)**2))+0.0791*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4520)**2))+0.0757*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4063)**2))+0.0743*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4096)**2))+0.0768*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3949)**2))+0.0746*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4037)**2))+0.0793*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4439)**2))+0.0798*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4307)**2))+0.0803*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4549)**2))+0.0803*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4299)**2))+0.0792*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4458)**2))+0.0792*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4315)**2))+0.0748*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4013)**2))+0.0796*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4374)**2))+0.0751*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3927)**2))+0.0793*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4405)**2))+0.0794*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4191)**2))+0.0790*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4471)**2))+0.0725*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3734)**2))+0.0794*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4363)**2))+0.0736*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4006)**2))+0.0806*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4290)**2))+0.0667*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3630)**2))+0.0692*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3489)**2))+0.0795*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4395)**2))+0.0677*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.3445)**2))+0.0771*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.4126)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8856)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8932)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8923)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8770)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8963)**2))+0.0014*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8993)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8993)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9016)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8858)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8632)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8897)**2))+0.0003*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8887)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8988)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8887)**2))+0.0006*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8819)**2))+0.0004*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8826)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9036)**2))+0.0003*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8946)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8819)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8929)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9025)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9146)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8882)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8970)**2))+0.0003*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9052)**2))+0.0004*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8944)**2))+0.0006*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8918)**2))+0.0005*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9016)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8896)**2))+0.0003*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8912)**2))+0.0005*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8917)**2))+0.0007*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9055)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8917)**2))+0.0005*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8961)**2))+0.0003*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9037)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8841)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9049)**2))+0.0003*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9049)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8991)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9009)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8933)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8963)**2))+0.0004*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9009)**2))+0.0008*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9040)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8984)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8730)**2))+0.0005*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8772)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9096)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8995)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9050)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8719)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8836)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8869)**2))+0.0005*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8967)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8934)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8934)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8980)**2))+0.0013*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8946)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9020)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8957)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9138)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8840)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8894)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8927)**2))+0.0003*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8829)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8997)**2))+0.0007*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8915)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9075)**2))+0.0003*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9030)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8930)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8872)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8962)**2))+0.0013*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8716)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8953)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9163)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8947)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9060)**2))+0.0015*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8809)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8990)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9000)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8922)**2))+0.0004*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9160)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9013)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9118)**2))+0.0002*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8932)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8985)**2))+0.0008*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8939)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8871)**2))+0.0003*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9002)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8979)**2))+0.0003*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9007)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8890)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8996)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8902)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8985)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8833)**2))+0.0009*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8812)**2))+0.0009*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9017)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.8777)**2))+0.0000*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-3.9045)**2))+1.7658*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6660)**2))+2.6625*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6816)**2))+2.8480*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6687)**2))+0.7417*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6581)**2))+2.8361*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6775)**2))+2.5493*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6740)**2))+2.8419*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6801)**2))+2.8156*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6693)**2))+2.0225*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6768)**2))+0.0015*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.5440)**2))+3.0303*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6562)**2))+2.2534*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6675)**2))+2.4332*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6775)**2))+2.7540*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6818)**2))+0.0003*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.5338)**2))+3.0794*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6638)**2))+3.0542*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6993)**2))+2.5248*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6741)**2))+1.0126*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6616)**2))+2.0927*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6674)**2))+2.2406*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6843)**2))+1.7495*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.7205)**2))+3.0602*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6633)**2))+3.0831*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6835)**2))+2.3690*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6920)**2))+2.9705*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6761)**2))+1.9959*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6591)**2))+2.9565*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6807)**2))+2.6436*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6707)**2))+3.0637*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6776)**2))+3.0925*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6719)**2))+2.5362*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.7013)**2))+2.7759*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6784)**2))+2.4267*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6759)**2))+2.7295*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6797)**2))+2.1589*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6530)**2))+3.0072*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6781)**2))+3.0566*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6768)**2))+2.8682*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6812)**2))+1.4341*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6767)**2))+2.8155*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6739)**2))+0.1091*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6674)**2))+1.9682*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6780)**2))+2.6790*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6589)**2))+2.7670*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6842)**2))+0.0034*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.5747)**2))+1.0480*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6440)**2))+2.6039*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6938)**2))+2.7190*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6833)**2))+2.9214*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6837)**2))+0.6360*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6415)**2))+0.0001*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6213)**2))+1.6841*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6600)**2))+2.9654*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6687)**2))+2.8913*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6652)**2))+2.0393*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6707)**2))+3.0833*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6877)**2))+3.0038*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6754)**2))+3.0287*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6994)**2))+2.6433*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6909)**2))+2.7269*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6919)**2))+1.5101*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6400)**2))+2.8046*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6676)**2))+2.9361*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6763)**2))+0.9224*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.5222)**2))+0.0149*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6250)**2))+0.4403*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6601)**2))+3.0702*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6908)**2))+2.5673*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6842)**2))+1.3515*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6596)**2))+2.2202*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6569)**2))+3.0804*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6822)**2))+0.9960*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6673)**2))+3.0568*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6677)**2))+2.7575*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.7040)**2))+2.1298*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6727)**2))+1.9641*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.7079)**2))+2.1419*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6631)**2))+1.7003*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6818)**2))+3.0215*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6838)**2))+3.0102*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6738)**2))+2.6841*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6883)**2))+3.0346*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6790)**2))+2.8531*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6951)**2))+2.8329*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6780)**2))+1.8481*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6781)**2))+2.8693*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6813)**2))+1.8209*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6601)**2))+2.8664*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6917)**2))+2.7389*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6884)**2))+2.9089*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6898)**2))+1.5409*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6713)**2))+3.0047*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6755)**2))+1.8520*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6767)**2))+3.1030*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.7000)**2))+1.0380*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6701)**2))+0.0246*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.5205)**2))+2.7070*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6915)**2))+0.9610*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6613)**2))+2.4082*(exp(-1000.0000000*(x-5.6841)**2)))/100)
h(x)=sin(-x)
plot f(x) title 'my data 1' with lines linestyle 1, \
g(x) title 'my data 2' with lines linestyle 2, \
h(x) title 'sin (-x)' with lines linestyle 3
```

While gnuplot plots the sine curve pretty smoothly, the sum of gaussian functions are evaluated rather crudely (as can be seen from the [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjoeF.png) near x = 5.5). How can I force gnuplot to evaluate the function accurately so that I get a smooth curve? Is there a step_size or mesh_size variable I can change to get a better numerical evaluation?

PS: I can obviously run this in MATLAB or Mathematica, however I am only trying to see if I can do it within GNUPLOT.

Comment: `set samples 1000`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7454159/2604213