# gnuplot: fragmented peaks on graph

Tags: gnuplot

I'm plotting some data fitted with Gaussians, but the peaks aren't smooth, it gets better only if I zoom in enough on the peak.

the output code is:
    set terminal pngcairo size 1200,800 enhanced font 'Verdana,10'

And the resulted plot:
[image: fractured peaks]

[image: smooth peaks]

How can i smoothen the curves?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've embedded your images into the question rather than leaving them as external links.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gnuplot x-axis resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454159/gnuplot-x-axis-resolution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set isosamples <N>` where N is the number of points on your plotting domain, the default might be too low

Comment: Indeed. Actually it is the "set samples <N>" option that solved my problem. Thanks!